# Ranking based on multiple columns

Tags: oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM5xe.jpg)I have a table with 3 columns as below. I need to write a query to find out whether there was any order after disconnect order based on order dates. That is if one account has multiple orders, I want to rank them and check whether Disconnect has the highest rank(if disconnect order has the highest rank against an account, disconnect is the last order). Thanks in advance.

```
Account no, Order, Order_date
101,Connect,1-1-2023
101,Modify,1-3-2023
103,Connect,1-2-2023
101,Disconnect,1-3-2023
```

query I tried -

```
SELECT account_no,order_id,order_date,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY created_t asc)rank_no
FROM table;
```

Comment: Please also include the output you expect and explain it.

Comment: And: what does 1-3-2023 represent? Is it 1st of March or 3rd of January?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  please find below.

This is the input data

Account no  Order  Order_date
101 Connect 01-Jan-23
101 Modify 01-Mar-23
103 Connect 01-Feb-23
101 Disconnect 07-Mar-23
103 Disconnect 05-Feb-23
103 Modify 04-Mar-23

and this is the expected output

Account no  Order  Order_date Rank
101 Connect 01-Jan-23 1
101 Modify 01-Mar-23 2
103 Connect 01-Feb-23 1
101 Disconnect 07-Mar-23 3
103 Disconnect 05-Feb-23 2
103 Modify 04-Mar-23 3

Logic: Orders against each account ranked based on the order date.

Comment: Add this data directly to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen kindly refer the image I added to the question. Expected result column is what I need.

Comment: Voting to close as critical information is lacking in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to write a query to find out whether there was any order after disconnect order based on order dates.

Add a `PARTITION BY` clause and change the `ORDER BY` clause from `ASC` to `DESC` so that the latest row is always ranked 1st and then you can just check if the `order_id` of the 1st ranked row is `Disconnect`. If you need to check that there was at least one row with the `order_id` of `Disconnect` then you can use the `COUNT` analytic function with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT account_no,
         order_id,
         order_date,
         RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY account_no
           ORDER BY created_t DESC
         ) AS rank_no,
         COUNT(CASE order_id WHEN 'Disconnect' THEN 1 END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY account_no
         ) AS has_disconnect
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE rnk      = 1
AND   order_id != 'Disconnect'
AND   has_disconnect > 0;
```

Or, from Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY account_no
  ORDER BY created_t DESC
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( ^ not_disconnect {- any_row*? disconnect -} )
  DEFINE
    not_disconnect AS order_id != 'Disconnect',
    disconnect     AS order_id =  'Disconnect'
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, @MT0 you have solved my problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EXISTS to find out such condition,
to get the rows of kind different of Disconnect having a Disconnect with the same account_no before them:

```
select d.* from table_name d
where order_id <> 'Disconnect'
    and exists(
        select 1 from table_name d1 
            where d1.account_no = d.account_no 
            -- or <= depending on your requirements
            and d1.order_date < d.order_date
            and d1.order_id = 'Disconnect'
    )
;
```

And if you want the Disconnect rows having a not Disconnect after them:

```
select d.* from table_name d
where order_id = 'Disconnect'
    and exists(
        select 1 from table_name d1 
            where d1.account_no = d.account_no 
            -- or >= depending on your requirements
            and d1.order_date > d.order_date
            and d1.order_id <> 'Disconnect'
    )
;
```